# how to change scal behavour

Tags: transforms, transform-orientation

simple technical question, how can I make the scale behave the same as move and rotate, when selecting one axis angel on the gizmo it should constraint to that axis, it does it with the move and rotate tool but not with the scale, I know I can press (x,z,y) to trigger that behavior but I want it to work on the gizmo itself, much appreciation.[image]

Comment: it should scale on Y when you manipulate the Y axis, maybe share your file to see why it doesn't work here

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, works fine for me. Are you making sure the axis is highlighted? I can't tell from your gif.

Comment: i think it's due to something i messed up in the keymap options, I'm sharing my file and keep in mind that the scale hotkey is "T" and the Move HotKey is "E "Rotation is "R" --- [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=GXs67aLo" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/GXs67aLo/)

Comment: @AkramFex It's probably a keymap problem then. You can go to Properties > Keymap and search in the "Key Binding" mode for "T", for instance, to see what other actions are assigned to that key and resolve it. Also, you have "Affect only: Locations" enabled so you can't rotate or scale your objects in object mode either, I don't know if that was intentional: https://i.imgur.com/FWOrBKK.png (By the way, your shortcuts don't come with the file, you'd need to send that separately after exporting it from Preferences > Keymap. Your file works fine with my keymap).

Comment: Sorry for the late replay, this is the hotkey file, Much appreciation for already giving it a try @Kuboå
 - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QjYEsrvybxNP9ylu8nimb6JGoXzcU-Wa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @AkramFex I still can't reproduce the error even with your keymap, and I can't think of anything that would break the gizmo's functionality. Are you a new user, btw? Because if you are, I wouldn't use this keymap of yours, it is *so* heavily edited down to the most basic functions. You couldn't follow any tutorials, for example. If you are not new and know what you like, of course, carry on...

Comment: Im kinda new but to blender and not to 3d, comming from c4d i cant work with blender if i use the native key maps, i have a long autohotkey file that runs aside to have a full control, but this issue it seems i cant have my grasp over it, if after you tried the files i sent you and you didn't have this issue so i don't know really what's the problem, and turning everything to default is no option!